# How do i call the function I created in my Model on the view

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, view, model

I just created this function in the model to see who im following in my social network... how do i call it in the view??

```
function isfollowing($following){

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('uid');

        $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('membership');
        $this->db->join('following', "membership.id = following.tofollow_id");
        $this->db->where("tofollow_id","$following");
        $this->db->where("user_id", "$user_id");


        $q = $this->db->get();      



    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return "yes";
    } else {
        return "no"; 
    }


}
```

Now in my VIEW how do i call it being that i had already made a function to get the current logged on user's id and that is equal to $r->id

How do i call it here?? what goes after the "==" in that if statement?

THE VIEW

```
<?php if ( $r->id == ): ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to call model function from view.
There are some alternatives about it. You can use anyone you like.

First

When you are loading a view call your model function and pass it in a variable
than this variable will be passed to view.

Controller

```
$following_status   =   $this->my_model->isfollowing($following);

$data['following_status']   =   $following_status;

$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

View

```
<p>$following_status</p>
```

Secound

If you want to be independent of model you can create helper which you can 
use anywhere in the application. You will have to create a CI instance to 
get it working.

custom_helper.php

```
function isfollowing($following)
{
    $CI =   get_instance();

    $user_id = $CI->session->userdata('uid');

    $CI->db->select('*');    
    $CI->db->from('membership');
    $CI->db->join('following', "membership.id = following.tofollow_id");
    $CI->db->where("tofollow_id","$following");
    $CI->db->where("user_id", "$user_id");

    $q = $CI->db->get();      

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return "yes";
    } else {
        return "no"; 
    }
}
```

View

```
//load the custom helper before using it (you can autoload of in autoload.php)
//or use common way $this->load->helper('custom');
<p>isfollowing($yourparameter)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do the following:

(1) Load your model in the controller that creates your page or auto load it

(2) In your view, type something like:

```
$this->The_custom_model->isfollowing($theinputvariable)
```

where `The_custom_model` is the model where you defined the `isfollowing()` function.

`$theinputvariable` is the appropriate argument value for your function.  Keep in mind that you have specified an object as the argument to your function so you need to think about that.

Answer (score 0):

this is an amended version to what raheel posted showing an if check - probably not necessary for your question, but to give you some things to think about...

```
 // check to see if anything come back from the database?
 if ( ! $data['following_status'] = $this->my_model->isfollowing($following) ) {  

 // nothing came back, jump to another method to deal with it
  $this->noFollowers() ; }

 // else we have a result, and its already set to data, so ready to go
 else {

   // do more here, call your view, etc 
 }
```

databases can go down even if the web page is working so its good to get in the habit of checking the results. the more error checks you can do in your controller and models, the cleaner your view files will be.

Answer (score 0):

To access model into your view you first load it into autoload file like this

```
   $autoload['model'] = array('model_name');
```

then in view you can get it by using this line of code

```
     $this->model_name->isfollowing($following)
```

in **isfollowing** you will pass your **tofollow_id**